# Is APT trying to downgrade a package?

Tags: apt, upgrade, downgrade

Since last month (or two) I am observing this kind of error when running `apt-get upgrade`:

```
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-common_1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2) over (1.9.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/logrotate.d/nginx', which is also in package nginx 1.10.1-1~wily
Preparing to unpack .../nginx-core_1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-core (1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2) over (1.9.3-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-core_1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/nginx', which is also in package nginx 1.10.1-1~wily
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

Though the whole upgrade process doesn't fail, I still have this error mentioned at the end of upgrade process:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-common_1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx-core_1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I understand it correctly, I have version **1.10.1** currently installed while *apt* is trying to install version *1.9.3* **over it**... I.e., it's trying to donwgrade it. Am I right? Is it possible that the newer version came from some PPA while the *older* one is coming from some official list?

I have Ubuntu 15.10 installed.

How can I prevent this *downgrade* to happen?

**EDIT:** Here an output from `apt-cache policy nginx`

```
nginx:
  Installed: 1.10.1-1~wily
  Candidate: 1.10.1-1~wily
  Version table:
 *** 1.10.1-1~wily 0
        500 http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ wily/nginx amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.10.0-1~wily 0
        500 http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ wily/nginx amd64 Packages
     1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.9.3-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/main amd64 Packages
     1.8.1-1~wily 0
        500 http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ wily/nginx amd64 Packages
     1.8.0-1~wily 0
        500 http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ wily/nginx amd64 Packages
```

Answer (score 2):

First I would check to see what package APT is configured to install (out of the available options), you can do this with:

```
apt-cache policy nginx
```

e.g.

```
% apt-cache policy nginx
nginx:
  Installed: 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Candidate: 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 500
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.9.15-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

This tells me that if I didn't already have nginx installed, apt would try and install the

```
1.10.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
```

version of nginx.
Then to install a particular - non candidate - package you can specify it as an option to `apt-get` e.g. from `man apt` ( I've truncated the output to make it easier to understand)

> SYNOPSIS
>          apt-get ... pkg [{=pkg_version_number ] ...

e.g.

```
apt-get install nginx=1.9.15-0ubuntu1
```

would install the non-candidate version of the `nginx` package if that was necessary. Note you may have to do some of your own dependency management in this case, but not always.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I have this output: `Installed: 1.10.1-1~wily` and `Candidate: 1.10.1-1~wily`, then version table with these versions: `1.10.1-1~wily 0`, `1.10.0-1~wily 0`, `1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2 0`, `1.9.3-1ubuntu1 0`, `1.8.1-1~wily 0` and `1.8.0-1~wily 0`. So it all should be fine except for `apt-get upgrade` tries to install `1.9.3-1ubuntu1.2 0` over my current newest version... I'll add this output to my question.